# Using Groovy command line script to exectue Java Spring Beans how do I stop the NoSuchBeanDefinitionException?

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I have written this Groovy script to load and execute some Java Spring Beans:

```
    @GrabResolver(name = 'libs.snapshot', root = 'http://ml1002pc:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot', m2compatible = 'true')
    @Grapes([
    @Grab(group = 'com.siemens.soarian.sf', module = 'BuildInformationService', version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT', changing = true),
    @Grab(group = 'com.siemens.soarian.sf', module = 'GapAnalyzer', version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT', changing = true)
    ])

    @GrabResolver(name = 'libs-release', root = 'http://ml1002pc:8081/artifactory/libs-release', m2compatible = 'true')
    @Grapes([
    @Grab(group = 'org.springframework', module = 'org.springframework.context', version = '3.0.5.RELEASE'),
    @Grab(group = 'org.springframework', module = 'org.springframework.context.support', version = '3.0.5.RELEASE'),
    @Grab(group = 'org.springframework', module = 'org.springframework.core', version = '3.0.5.RELEASE'),
    @Grab(group = 'org.springframework', module = 'org.springframework.beans', version = '3.0.5.RELEASE'),
    @Grab(group = 'org.springframework', module = 'org.springframework.asm', version = '3.0.5.RELEASE'),
    @Grab(group = 'org.springframework', module = 'org.springframework.aop', version = '3.0.5.RELEASE'),
    @Grab(group = 'org.springframework', module = 'org.springframework.aspects', version = '3.0.5.RELEASE'),
    @Grab(group = 'org.springframework', module = 'org.springframework.expression', version = '3.0.5.RELEASE'),
    @Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-lang:2.6'),
    @Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-collections:3.2.1'),
    @Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-logging:1.1.1'),
    @Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp:1.4'),
    @Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-pool:1.6'),
    @Grab('com.microsoft:sqljdbc:1.2'),
    ])
    @GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)

    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    import com.siemens.soarian.sf.build.BuildInformationService;
    import com.siemens.soarian.sf.gap.*

    public class CommandLineWrapper {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:**/META-INF/applicationContext*.xml");

            GapAnalyzer gapAnalyzer = (GapAnalyzer) ctx.getBean("gapAnalyzer");
        }
    }
```

The application context I am trying to load has this bean declaration:

```
    <bean id="gapAnalyzer" class="com.siemens.soarian.sf.gap.GapAnalyzerImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="buildInformationService"/>
    </bean>
```

The exception I get at command line is:

```
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@14f1726: startup date [Mon Jan 21 10:46:04 EST 2013 ]; root of context hierarchy 
Jan 21, 2013 10:46:04 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1e22c75: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
Caught: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'gapAnalyzer' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'gapAnalyzer' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1075)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory$getBean.call(Unknown Source)
```

However, running this script causes a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException on line 40 as if Spring cannot find the bean spec.

If I use a Spring partial integration test written in Java and running in Eclipse I can load the bean and the other beans it needs just fine.  It loads as expected.

I inspected the jars downloaded by Grape located at my Windows Home **/.groovy** and all jars are present.

Based on my reading of [Adding Things to the Classpath](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running) Grape should be taking care of getting these jars on my classpath.

I am running:

- Windows XP
- Eclipse Juno
- Groovy 2.0.6
- Sun JVM: 1.6.0_33
- Spring 3.0.5.RELEASE
- Artifactory 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out by working on a Grails project using the same services that I am able to get Groovy Grapes to download the dependencies and Spring to resolve them is I simply do this:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
```

The key differences is I cleaned up the classpath pattern.  The other patterns all failed both in my Grails app and here.

Answer (score 0):

Give your bean a `name` attribute and pass that to `getBean` instead of the `id`.

Edit:

You should be seeing something like this being logged:

```
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@318a41cf: startup date [Mon Jan 21 20:51:21 MST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [./META-INF/spring-conf.xml]
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4ed1102f: defining beans [gapAnalyzer]; root of factory hierarchy
```

In particular, it should show a message with the file name and list the declared beans.  If you're not seeing this, the XML configuration file is not being read.  Spring fails silently if it can't find it.

Comment: I tried this approach but I am still experiencing the same failure.  I added a name attribute and the name differs from the id (I left the id since our standards/governance require id).  I even tried moving the jars in question to the lib folder of my groovy install and removing them from ~/.groovy and commenting out the Grape Grabs for our bean jars.  Will try removing the id attributes and keeping just the name attributes.

Comment: Sorry, I think that was a red herring.  The issue is probably related to finding the spring configuration.  See edit above.

Comment: Well it seems that Spring cannot find it even if Groovy can (there are imports and references in my script which work).  Do not see the desired INFO from Spring regarding loading the context:

`INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@21b42f: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy`

Comment: Well I did some more experiments and decided, based on your post to alter this code `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:**/META-INF/applicationContext.xml")` which works in Java just fine to be this code `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("./META-INF/applicationContext.xml")`  which finds the beans and loads the files.  I stil have another error but it may be related to the **name** vs. **id** issue. I will post back when I have more time to experiment with this.  So far, you have been very helpful.

Comment: ** Correction ** all application context xmls are not being found and loaded.  So, something else is amiss I will need to do more research.

Answer (score 0):

This script:

```
@Grab('org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.1.RELEASE')
@Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1')
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

def ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
def su = ctx.getBean('su')
assert su.swapCase('Fee Fi Fo Fum') == 'fEE fI fO fUM'
```

With this XML file in the same directory works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
   <bean id="su" class="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` ever expands its constructor argument into a `Resource[]` array.  So Spring thinks you are trying to create a context from a non-existent (single) file called `**/META-INF/applicationContext*.xml`.  Unsurprisingly that doesn't work (and wouldn't work in Java or Groovy).  The ant-style patterns are only expanded when a String needs to be converted to a `Resource[]`, for instance when specifying an `<import/>` in XML.  If you want to do it without an import I suggest you use the `ResourceArrayPropertyEditor` directly in conjunction with a `GenericXmlApplicationContext` (which accepts a `Resource[]` as a constructor argument).